# Socket.io Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked Error

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, content-security-policy

I am trying to run a websocket server with nodejs and express. The server side code is simple code example given on the Socket.io documentation.

**I am using the latest Version of Socket.io (v4.5.4)**

```
const app = express();

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://0.0.0.0:8000",
    credentials: true,
  },
  allowRequest: (req, callback) => {
    console.log("ALLOWING REQ");
    callback(null, true);
  },
  path: "/ws",
});

io.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("Connected");
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000`);
});
```

But when I tried to connect to the websocket from by browser by typing this on the console:

`new WebSocket("ws://0.0.0.0:8000/ws")`

I am getting this error

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ws://0.0.0.0:8000/ws (“default-src”)`

Also this is the Exception message if it helps

```
Exception { name: "NS_ERROR_CONTENT_BLOCKED", message: "", result: 2153644038, filename: "debugger eval code", lineNumber: 1, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "@debugger eval code:1:1\n" }
```

Can anyone please help me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. it's working fine and you can set allow IPs as well.

```
const app = express();

const httpServer = createServer(app);

let whitelist = ['*']
let corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || whitelist.indexOf('*') !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
app.use("/", cors(corsOptions), index);

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

io.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("Connected");
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000`);
});
```